# OnModelCreating setting up cascade delete with HasMany causing problems

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Consider the 2 alternative lines:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<CommissionStructure>().HasMany(c => c.CommissionUnits).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CommissionStructure>().HasMany<CommissionUnit>(c=>c.CommissionUnits).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

First line complains about TTarget cannot being inferred from the usage.

So I tried the 2nd line, however it now complains about not being able to convert IEnumerable to ICollection even though my model is not defined anywhere as an ICollection.

Any ideas? The CommissionUnits are a nested IEnumerable collection inside CommissionStructure. This was an IList before, but IList has problems when doing a ToList() from a LINQ query in my repository where OrderBy has been used. This is why I exposed IEnumerable not IList on my repository.  So I'm kind of stuck between a rock & a hard place!

Comment: Which problem did you have with `IList<T>` exactly? I'm using `IList<T>` quite frequently as navigation property and could not see a problem until now.

Comment: My problem occurred only when within my repository I needed to OrderBy() to sort.  I always return IList from the repo class, but try and use OrderBy and IList and you will run into difficulty.  myQuery.ToList() cannot work as the query wants to return an IOrderedEnumerable. That is my big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasMany` as a method of `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` has this signature:

```
HasMany<TTarget>(Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TTarget>>> expression)
```

which means that you cannot use `IEnumerable<T>` for navigation properties. You need `ICollection<T>` or a derived collection type. This explains both compiler errors you had.

Comment: Hi, does this mean that when defining my code-first entity model the relationships can be defined with IList or ICollection? I'm having real problems using IList because the repository cannot convert the result of a LINQ orderby expression back to an IList and I guess the same with ICollection?

Comment: Yes, you can use `ICollection`, `IList` and even concrete classes like `Hashset` or `List` or `ObservableCollection` or..or..or..., so ICollection or every interface which derives from it or any class which implements ICollection. But not IEnumerable since it's too "low level", it doesn't derive from ICollection. You need to show an example what problems are you having with IList - perhaps better as a new question.

Comment: Here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488747/onmodelcreating-setting-up-cascade-delete-with-hasmany-causing-problems

This question is really a side-effect/sub problem of a wider problem which is my link here.